# Is Nurmengard Castle unprotected?

Tags: harry-potter, fantastic-beasts, the-secrets-of-dumbledore

In *Secrets of Dumbledore*, we see that Yusuf Kama was able to enter Nurmengard Castle's exterior courtyard without having to bypass any protective enchantments like the Death Eaters do to Hogwarts before the Battle of Hogwarts in *Deathly Hallows*. In a deleted scene, Albus Dumbledore also goes to Nurmengard Castle to talk about the scars on Credence's hand, presumably after their duel, as they seem to be cordial in their conversation.

Why would someone as intelligent, prudent, and powerful as Gellert Grindelwald not protect the castle from unwanted intruders? Did he not think that by leaving the castle unprotected, that he could be killed whilst asleep, essentially putting an end to his revolution?